# How to convert TImage and TImageControl coordinates to underlying bitmap coordinates?

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder, timage

I'm working on a small C++Builder FireMonkey project that uses both `TImage` and `TImageControl` components.

I'm trying to display the RGB pixel colors of the underlying bitmaps when the mouse moves over both of these controls.  The online help has a couple of functions called `ConvertLocalPointTo` and `ConvertLocalPointFrom`.  C++Builder help doesn't have any information on these routines.

I also noticed that `TImageControl` has a `MarginWrapMode` property which allows you to center and fill the bitmap to the control, whereas `TImage` doesn't.

What are they defining as a local point?  Is that the point in the control, or the point in the bitmap? When you look in the help file, the typical Embarcadero help message is shown:

> Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional information.

Does anyone have a programming example of how to convert between the 2 coordinate systems?

Comment: The `ConvertLocalPoint[To|From]` methods are for converting a point with one UI control into a point within another UI control. Basically, in this context, "local" and "absolute" coordinates in FMX are the equivalent of "client" and "screen" coordinates in Win32.

Comment: Thanks Remy!  So how does one convert the TImage co-ordinates exposed in the OnMouseMove event to the underlying Bitmap Points (assuming that the bitmap is stretched to fill the entire TImage control)?

Answer (score 0):

When a Bitmap fills the client area of a `TImage/Control`, converting a `TImage`-local coordinate into a `TBitmap`-local coordinate is fairly simple. Calculate a ratio of the `TImage` X coordinate to the `TImage` width, and then apply that same ratio to the `TBitmap` width to get the `TBitmap` X coordinate, eg:

`BitmapX := (ImageX / ImageWidth) * BitmapWidth`

Then, do the same for the Y coordinates relative to the heights.

Obviously, if the `TBitmap` does not fully fill the `TImage`, then you will have to subtract any margins, offsets, etc from the `ImageX`/`ImageY` and `ImageWidth`/`ImageHeight` as needed.

Comment: Thanks Remy.  If the bitmap is centered in the TImage/Control Components and not filling the entire client area of the TImage/Control component, that could be quite challenging.

Comment: Not really. You know the Bitmap sizes, and you know the TImage sizes, so calculating margins and offsets is a small adjustment.